# ConnectionString in localhost vs. actual host

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hosting, connection-string, localhost, web-hosting

In local host I have connectionstring (in web.config file) as below:

```
<add name="TamizharThalamEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TamizharThalam.csdl|res://*/Models.TamizharThalam.ssdl|res://*/Models.TamizharThalam.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=./SQLEXPRESS; attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TamizharThalam.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

I hosted my site with netcetera..They told me change the connection string as below:

Data Source=sql1101.netcetera.co.uk;Initial Catalog=YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE;User Id=YOUR DATABASE USERNAME HERE;Password=YOUR DATABASEsomepwd

So changed web.config as below:

```
data source=sql1101.netcetera.co.uk; Initial Catalog=TamizharThalam;
```

But my website is not working....

Please let me know how to change the connectionString correctly

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to an Microsoft SQL Database your web.config key setting should look something like this

```
<add name="TamizharThalamEntities" connectionString="Data Source=sql1101.netcetera.co.uk;Initial Catalog=YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE;User Id=YOUR DATABASE USERNAME HERE;Password=YOUR DATABASEsomepwd" provider="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm in a similar situation where I am using EntityFramework on a SQL Express instance locally. I have modified my connection string on my web host files to point to the hosted database that I have (on SQL Server 2008). The problem lies with the database initialisation strategy. With EntityFramework, it tries to drop the database and recreate it - but this isn't possible with a hosted database as users aren't able to delete and create databases on a whim. I have an existing hosted database - and I want to use this without dropping and recreating. Any ideas how I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds to me that your hosted database schema and your code do not match so its trying to bring your schema up to date (by dropping and recreating); are you doing code first development? if so you can run the update-datatabase -verbose command from the package manager console so that your code matches the remote schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your connection string to:

```
data source=sql1101.netcetera.co.uk; Initial Catalog=TamizharThalam;
```

You are not putting in the credentials to log onto the instance/database as.  You absolutely need to put in a user name and password (if you're not using *integrated security*) so that your application can authenticate to the instance/database.

[ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) is by far the best site for connection string help, and it'll get you set up with the correct conn string.